# ImportError: No module named myapp.settings

Tags: pythonanywhere

I created a Django app locally, and I would like to host it on PythonAnywhere.com. I've followed the directions at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango and created a `virtualenv` with 1.9 installed. However, when I try to run my app, I get the error `ImportError: No module named myapp.settings`

Here is my `username_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py`

```
import os
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/rhpt'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(project_home)

# set environment variable to tell django where your settings.py is
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

# serve django via WSGI
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I also tried `myapp.my_app.settings` without success.

My tree

```
myapp                                                                                                                                 
├── my_app                                                                                                                            
│   ├── __init__.py                                                                                                                        
│   ├── settings.py                                                                                                                        
│   ├── urls.py                                                                                                                            
│   └── wsgi.py                                                                                                                            
├── get_data                                                                                                                               
│   ├── __init__.py                                                                                                                        
│   ├── admin.py                                                                                                                           
│   ├── models.py                                                                                                                          
│   ├── tests.py                                                                                                                           
│   ├── urls.py                                                                                                                            
│   └── views.py                                                                                                                           
└── manage.py
```

Comment: Just for clarification -- when you say your `wsgi.py`, do you mean the WSGI file linked to from the PythonAnywhere "Web" tab (probably actually called something like `yourusername_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py` or the `wsgi.py` inside your Django code tree?  The code you give should be in the former one of those.

Comment: the wsgi.py inside the PythonAnywhere "Web" tab. I've edited the question with the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for updating that!

Comment: So, to debug this, think about how the settings module is imported.  You have `/home/rhpt` on your Python path.  And your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is `myapp.settings`.  This means that your settings will be loading from the file `/home/rhpt/myapp/settings.py`.  Is that definitely where your settings are?

Comment: My settings are in `/home/rhpt/myapp/my_app/settings.py`. However, if I change the path to myapp.my_app.settings.py I still get an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your `settings.py` file is in /home/rhpt/myapp/my_app/settings.py

then this part

```
# add your project directory to the sys.path 
project_home = u'/home/rhpt'
```

needs to be

```
# add your project directory to the sys.path 
project_home = u'/home/rhpt/myapp'
```

and also keep this

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_app.settings'
```

Comment: there's a general guide to debugging import errors and other wsgi config issues on PythonAnywhere here:  https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you put an empty

> `__init__.py`

in the same folder as the settings.py it worked for me